# InputStreamResponseListener timeout exception while doing saxon

Tags: xml, exception, inputstream, saxon

here is my sample saxon transformation code and im having an error.

```
public static boolean transformXML(Source xmlSrc, Source xsltSrc,
        OutputStream output, HashMap<String, String> parameters) {
    boolean retVal = false;
    try {
        Processor proc = new Processor(false);
        XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
        XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(xsltSrc);
        XdmNode source = proc.newDocumentBuilder().build(xmlSrc);
        Serializer outputSerializer = new Serializer();
        outputSerializer.setOutputStream(output);
        XsltTransformer trans = exp.load();
        trans.setInitialContextNode(source);
        trans.setDestination(outputSerializer);
        trans.transform();
        retVal = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Unexpected Exception", ex);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

If I have > 15mb xmlsource this is the error that I'm getting after doing the trans.transform():

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.InputStreamResponseListener.get(InputStreamResponseListener.java:226)
at org.restlet.ext.jetty.internal.JettyClientCall.sendRequest(JettyClientCall.java:275)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:105)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:275)
at com.ti.itg.peit.core.ftds.http.util.HTTPRequest.genericRequest(HTTPRequest.java:115)
at com.ti.itg.peit.core.ftds.http.util.HTTPRequest.getRequest(HTTPRequest.java:72)
```

### EDIT:

```
private StringBuffer processXSLT(
        final StringBuffer xmlSrc) {
    StringBuffer retVal = new StringBuffer();
    try {

        // to reduce file or content size.
        String compressTextXMLSrc = xmlSrc.toString()
                .replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

        // Dump file into a temp dir named input.xml;
        String inputDmp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
                + "input.xml";
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(inputDmp), compressTextXMLSrc );
        // END dump: sample file size > 19mb

        // get file .xslt
        String xsltFile = getResourceProperties()
                .getXsltFile();

        String outputDmp= System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "output.xml";

        // XSLT File Set systemID
        Source xsltFile = new SAXSource(
                new InputSource(xsltFile));
        xsltFile.setSystemId(xsltFile);

        try {
            InputStream test = IOUtils.toInputStream(compressTextXMLSrc);
            Processor proc = new Processor(false);
            XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();

            XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(xsltFile);

            DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
            builder.setLineNumbering(true);

            // Get input File from temp dir
            XdmNode source = builder
                    .build(new StreamSource(new File(inputDmp)));

            Serializer outputSerializer = new Serializer();
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(outputDmp));
            outputSerializer.setOutputStream(output);
            XsltTransformer trans = exp.load();
            trans.setInitialContextNode(source);
            trans.setDestination(outputSerializer);
            trans.transform();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Caught an exception: ", ex);
        retVal = null;
    }
    return retVal;
}
// END
```

**XdmNode source = builder
                        .build(new StreamSource(new File(inputDmp))); this is where im getting this error. But if i have lower mb file size, I did not encounter this**

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.InputStreamResponseListener.get(InputStreamResponseListener.java:226)
at org.restlet.ext.jetty.internal.JettyClientCall.sendRequest(JettyClientCall.java:275)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:105)
at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)
at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:275)
at com.ti.itg.peit.core.ftds.http.util.HTTPRequest.genericRequest(HTTPRequest.java:115)
at com.ti.itg.peit.core.ftds.http.util.HTTPRequest.getRequest(HTTPRequest.java:72)
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any connection between the source code and the stack trace. Is your outputStream perhaps connected to some HTTP machinery? Does it all work if you supply a different output stream?

Comment: Hi Michael Kay I found that in this line that cause the error: XdmNode source = builder
                    .build(new StreamSource(new File(inputDmp)));

Comment: this is where i dump my xml into temp dir. then getting this when building XdmNode source

Comment: My guess would be that the XML file you are reading has references to a DTD using an http-based URI, and that the failure occurs trying to dereference this URI. And the TimeoutException means exactly what it says; an HTTP request was made for some remote resource, and the client has given up waiting for the server to respond.